# UIScrollView not working in UIView using Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

In iOS, I had faced issue while creating a form like some user profile registration. I have added the UIScrollView in but still is not scroll page.

```
View(MAINVIEW)
  ScrollView
    View
      Label
       ..
       ..
```

above I have mentioned the structure of the UIView. Please any one explain clearly, whether it possible to achieve using storyboard? or programmatically? I have used autolayout with navigation bar with out using navigation controller. so I need to scrollview after the navigation bar. need like ( fixed header ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can achieve using storyboard. please see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyTFe6TP_hk) youtube video for using scrollviews.

Comment: It is possible for doing fixed navigation bar after scrollview

Comment: you can set the constraints according to your navigation bar to the scrollview.

Comment: Hi.. I need for auto layout for universal application. in that explain in only for iphone. whether any sample video for universal app.

Comment: Hi @vara . in this tutorial they are changing the size class for iPhone layout. if you want to make it universal don't change the size class and change the device to universal and all other constraint are as it is and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks. Its Working fine